# Creating new complex index with pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, concatenation, dataframe

I'm trying to concatenate the columns 'A' and 'C' in a Dataframe like the following to use it as a new Index:

```
     A  |  B  |  C  |  ...
---------------------------
 0   5  | djn |  0  |  ...
 1   5  | vlv |  1  |  ...
 2   5  | bla |  2  |  ...
 3   5  | ses |  3  |  ...
 4   5  | dug |  4  |  ...
```

The desired result would be a Dataframe which is similar to the following result:

```
         A  |  B  |  C  |  ...
-------------------------------
 05000   5  | djn |  0  |  ...
 05001   5  | vlv |  1  |  ...
 05002   5  | bla |  2  |  ...
 05003   5  | ses |  3  |  ...
 05004   5  | dug |  4  |  ...
```

I've searched my eyes off, does someone know how to manipulate a dataframe to get such result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#dummying up a dataframe
cf['A'] = 5*[5]
cf['C'] = range(5)
cf['B'] = list('qwert')
#putting together two columns into a new one -- EDITED so string formatting is OK
cf['D'] = map(lambda x: str(x).zfill(5), 1000*cf.A + cf.C)
# use it as the index
cf.index = cf.D
# we don't need it as a column
cf.drop('D', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(cf.to_csv())
```

> ```
> D,A,C,B
> 05000,5,0,q
> 05001,5,1,w
> 05002,5,2,e
> 05003,5,3,r
> 05004,5,4,t
> ```

That said, I suspect you'd be safer with multi-indexing (what if the values in B go above 999....), or sorting or grouping on multi-columns.

Comment: In my case I can figure out the maximum before-hand but multi-indexing could be an option. BTW. How can I do this with 0-padding and turn it in to a string format?

Comment: Look up string formats and add that to the line that creates cf['D'].

Comment: ... okay, I added string formatting. Have to say it gives me the heebie-jeebies to do this *in the data* -- I'd keep that as a pretty-for-humans option in reports, or such, and multi-index the data.

Comment: It's a pretty for human option! ;-) Thank you very much! I have another one I'll use for the real jobs! ;-)

Comment: Hey @cphlewis, I used your solution but had to turn it in to a for loop because when transformed into a string it would save the whole concated index in each entry. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110566/python-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-strange-format Do you know why?

Comment: It's casting it to string that's doing it. Hm; I'll see if it's doable in one line...

Comment: Wait, hang on, now I'm confused; if you're writing it out to csv, which will translate everything to strings, why do you need to translate to strings in the data? For the zero-padding?

Comment: Exactly, it would be useful for reports... In processing its dropped along with a couple of other columns.

Comment: Okay; I have it fixed. So embarassing not to have had a whole copy-paste-with-results example to start with...

Comment: Thank you @cphlewis, I asked it now to now what alternatives there were but didn't remember the map lamba solution. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73889/discussion-between-cphlewis-and-cmpsoares).