# Python Pandas DataFrame to_csv strange format

Tags: python, csv, pandas, format, dataframe

I'm trying to export a large DataFrame to a conventional CSV, instead when I use the method to_csv I get the following formatting:

```
ConcatIndex,FileID,FileName,ID,Tag,Level,Sublevels,Parent,Parent ID,Children,Descendants,Attributes,Attribute Array,Characters,Words,URLs,URL Array,Diferent URL Domains,Diferent URL SubDomains,Diferent URL Suffixes,Diferent URL Full Domains,Relevant,Relevant for Headline,Relevant for Body,Content,Real Content,Real Characters,Real Words,Real URLs,Real URL Array,Real Diferent URL Domains,Real Diferent URL SubDomains,Real Diferent URL Suffixes,Real Diferent URL Full Domains,<a>,<abbr>,<acronym>,<address>,<applet>,<area>,<article>,<aside>,<audio>,<b>,<base>,<basefont>,<bdi>,<bdo>,<big>,<blockquote>,<body>,<br>,<button>,<canvas>,<caption>,<center>,<cite>,<code>,<col>,<colgroup>,<datalist>,<dd>,<del>,<details>,<dfn>,<dialog>,<dir>,<div>,<dl>,<dt>,<em>,<embed>,<fieldset>,<figcaption>,<figure>,<font>,<footer>,<form>,<frame>,<frameset>,<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>,<head>,<header>,<hgroup>,<hr>,<html>,<i>,<iframe>,<img>,<input>,<ins>,<kbd>,<keygen>,<label>,<legend>,<li>,<link>,<main>,<map>,<mark>,<menu>,<menuitem>,<meta>,<meter>,<nav>,<noframes>,<noscript>,<object>,<ol>,<optgroup>,<option>,<output>,<p>,<param>,<pre>,<progress>,<q>,<rp>,<rt>,<ruby>,<s>,<samp>,<script>,<section>,<select>,<small>,<source>,<span>,<strike>,<strong>,<style>,<sub>,<summary>,<sup>,<table>,<tbody>,<td>,<textarea>,<tfoot>,<th>,<thead>,<time>,<title>,<tr>,<track>,<tt>,<u>,<ul>,<var>,<video>,<wbr>,<a>Parent,<abbr>Parent,<acronym>Parent,<address>Parent,<applet>Parent,<area>Parent,<article>Parent,<aside>Parent,<audio>Parent,<b>Parent,<base>Parent,<basefont>Parent,<bdi>Parent,<bdo>Parent,<big>Parent,<blockquote>Parent,<body>Parent,<br>Parent,<button>Parent,<canvas>Parent,<caption>Parent,<center>Parent,<cite>Parent,<code>Parent,<col>Parent,<colgroup>Parent,<datalist>Parent,<dd>Parent,<del>Parent,<details>Parent,<dfn>Parent,<dialog>Parent,<dir>Parent,<div>Parent,<dl>Parent,<dt>Parent,<em>Parent,<embed>Parent,<fieldset>Parent,<figcaption>Parent,<figure>Parent,<font>Parent,<footer>Parent,<form>Parent,<frame>Parent,<frameset>Parent,<h1>Parent,<h2>Parent,<h3>Parent,<h4>Parent,<h5>Parent,<h6>Parent,<head>Parent,<header>Parent,<hgroup>Parent,<hr>Parent,<html>Parent,<i>Parent,<iframe>Parent,<img>Parent,<input>Parent,<ins>Parent,<kbd>Parent,<keygen>Parent,<label>Parent,<legend>Parent,<li>Parent,<link>Parent,<main>Parent,<map>Parent,<mark>Parent,<menu>Parent,<menuitem>Parent,<meta>Parent,<meter>Parent,<nav>Parent,<noframes>Parent,<noscript>Parent,<object>Parent,<ol>Parent,<optgroup>Parent,<option>Parent,<output>Parent,<p>Parent,<param>Parent,<pre>Parent,<progress>Parent,<q>Parent,<rp>Parent,<rt>Parent,<ruby>Parent,<s>Parent,<samp>Parent,<script>Parent,<section>Parent,<select>Parent,<small>Parent,<source>Parent,<span>Parent,<strike>Parent,<strong>Parent,<style>Parent,<sub>Parent,<summary>Parent,<sup>Parent,<table>Parent,<tbody>Parent,<td>Parent,<textarea>Parent,<tfoot>Parent,<th>Parent,<thead>Parent,<time>Parent,<title>Parent,<tr>Parent,<track>Parent,<tt>Parent,<u>Parent,<ul>Parent,<var>Parent,<video>Parent,<wbr>Parent,<a>child,<abbr>child,<acronym>child,<address>child,<applet>child,<area>child,<article>child,<aside>child,<audio>child,<b>child,<base>child,<basefont>child,<bdi>child,<bdo>child,<big>child,<blockquote>child,<body>child,<br>child,<button>child,<canvas>child,<caption>child,<center>child,<cite>child,<code>child,<col>child,<colgroup>child,<datalist>child,<dd>child,<del>child,<details>child,<dfn>child,<dialog>child,<dir>child,<div>child,<dl>child,<dt>child,<em>child,<embed>child,<fieldset>child,<figcaption>child,<figure>child,<font>child,<footer>child,<form>child,<frame>child,<frameset>child,<h1>child,<h2>child,<h3>child,<h4>child,<h5>child,<h6>child,<head>child,<header>child,<hgroup>child,<hr>child,<html>child,<i>child,<iframe>child,<img>child,<input>child,<ins>child,<kbd>child,<keygen>child,<label>child,<legend>child,<li>child,<link>child,<main>child,<map>child,<mark>child,<menu>child,<menuitem>child,<meta>child,<meter>child,<nav>child,<noframes>child,<noscript>child,<object>child,<ol>child,<optgroup>child,<option>child,<output>child,<p>child,<param>child,<pre>child,<progress>child,<q>child,<rp>child,<rt>child,<ruby>child,<s>child,<samp>child,<script>child,<section>child,<select>child,<small>child,<source>child,<span>child,<strike>child,<strong>child,<style>child,<sub>child,<summary>child,<sup>child,<table>child,<tbody>child,<td>child,<textarea>child,<tfoot>child,<th>child,<thead>child,<time>child,<title>child,<tr>child,<track>child,<tt>child,<u>child,<ul>child,<var>child,<video>child,<wbr>child,<a>desc,<abbr>desc,<acronym>desc,<address>desc,<applet>desc,<area>desc,<article>desc,<aside>desc,<audio>desc,<b>desc,<base>desc,<basefont>desc,<bdi>desc,<bdo>desc,<big>desc,<blockquote>desc,<body>desc,<br>desc,<button>desc,<canvas>desc,<caption>desc,<center>desc,<cite>desc,<code>desc,<col>desc,<colgroup>desc,<datalist>desc,<dd>desc,<del>desc,<details>desc,<dfn>desc,<dialog>desc,<dir>desc,<div>desc,<dl>desc,<dt>desc,<em>desc,<embed>desc,<fieldset>desc,<figcaption>desc,<figure>desc,<font>desc,<footer>desc,<form>desc,<frame>desc,<frameset>desc,<h1>desc,<h2>desc,<h3>desc,<h4>desc,<h5>desc,<h6>desc,<head>desc,<header>desc,<hgroup>desc,<hr>desc,<html>desc,<i>desc,<iframe>desc,<img>desc,<input>desc,<ins>desc,<kbd>desc,<keygen>desc,<label>desc,<legend>desc,<li>desc,<link>desc,<main>desc,<map>desc,<mark>desc,<menu>desc,<menuitem>desc,<meta>desc,<meter>desc,<nav>desc,<noframes>desc,<noscript>desc,<object>desc,<ol>desc,<optgroup>desc,<option>desc,<output>desc,<p>desc,<param>desc,<pre>desc,<progress>desc,<q>desc,<rp>desc,<rt>desc,<ruby>desc,<s>desc,<samp>desc,<script>desc,<section>desc,<select>desc,<small>desc,<source>desc,<span>desc,<strike>desc,<strong>desc,<style>desc,<sub>desc,<summary>desc,<sup>desc,<table>desc,<tbody>desc,<td>desc,<textarea>desc,<tfoot>desc,<th>desc,<thead>desc,<time>desc,<title>desc,<tr>desc,<track>desc,<tt>desc,<u>desc,<ul>desc,<var>desc,<video>desc,<wbr>desc,Attribute<hidden>,Attribute<high>,Attribute<href>,Attribute<hreflang>,Attribute<http-equiv>,Attribute<icon>,Attribute<id>,Attribute<ismap>,Attribute<itemprop>,Attribute<keytype>,Attribute<kind>,Attribute<label>,Attribute<lang>,Attribute<language>,Attribute<list>,Attribute<loop>,Attribute<low>,Attribute<manifest>,Attribute<max>,Attribute<maxlength>,Attribute<media>,Attribute<method>,Attribute<min>,Attribute<multiple>,Attribute<name>,Attribute<novalidate>,Attribute<open>,Attribute<optimum>,Attribute<pattern>,Attribute<ping>,Attribute<placeholder>,Attribute<poster>,Attribute<preload>,Attribute<pubdate>,Attribute<radiogroup>,Attribute<readonly>,Attribute<rel>,Attribute<required>,Attribute<reversed>,Attribute<rows>,Attribute<rowspan>,Attribute<sandbox>,Attribute<spellcheck>,Attribute<scope>,Attribute<scoped>,Attribute<seamless>,Attribute<selected>,Attribute<shape>,Attribute<size>,Attribute<sizes>,Attribute<span>,Attribute<src>,Attribute<srcdoc>,Attribute<srclang>,Attribute<srcset>,Attribute<start>,Attribute<step>,Attribute<style>,Attribute<summary>,Attribute<tabindex>,Attribute<target>,Attribute<title>,Attribute<type>,Attribute<usemap>,Attribute<value>,Attribute<width>,Attribute<wrap>,Attribute<border>,Attribute<buffered>,Attribute<challenge>,Attribute<charset>,Attribute<checked>,Attribute<cite>,Attribute<class>,Attribute<code>,Attribute<codebase>,Attribute<color>,Attribute<cols>,Attribute<colspan>,Attribute<content>,Attribute<contenteditable>,Attribute<contextmenu>,Attribute<controls>,Attribute<coords>,Attribute<data>,Attribute<data-*>,Attribute<datetime>,Attribute<default>,Attribute<defer>,Attribute<dir>,Attribute<dirname>,Attribute<disabled>,Attribute<download>,Attribute<draggable>,Attribute<dropzone>,Attribute<enctype>,Attribute<for>,Attribute<form>,Attribute<formaction>,Attribute<headers>,Attribute<height>,Attribute<accept>,Attribute<accept-charset>,Attribute<accesskey>,Attribute<action>,Attribute<align>,Attribute<alt>,Attribute<async>,Attribute<autocomplete>,Attribute<autofocus>,Attribute<autoplay>,Attribute<autosave>,Attribute<bgcolor>,Concatenated String Index,ConcatIndex
0,0,./dataset_html/diario_digital/428001.html,0,html,0,17,[document],,4,1477,1,['xmlns'],10926,1492,60,"['http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt', 'http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js', 'http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/dinheiro_digital/news.asp?id_news=132358', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/dinheiro_digital/news.asp?id_news=132356', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/dinheiro_digital/news.asp?id_news=132353', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/disco_digital/news.asp?id_news=37701', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/disco_digital/news.asp?id_news=37693', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/disco_digital/news.asp?id_news=37694', 'http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=300x250&type=mrec&pos=2&TileID=', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/disco_digital/news.asp?id_news=37694', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/disco_digital/news.asp?id_news=37383', 'http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=300x250&type=mrec&pos=1&TileID=', 'http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=300x100&type=banner&pos=2&TileID=', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=83&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=83&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/horoscopo.asp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/new/news.asp?section_id=33&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/section.asp?section_id=138', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/section.asp?section_id=185', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/section.asp?section_id=185', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/section.asp?section_id=185', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=126&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=126&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/section.asp?section_id=65', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=78&amp', 'http://www.anf.pt/', 'http://www.estradasdeportugal.pt/site/v3/?id_pagina=&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/section.asp?section_id=91', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://www.diariodigital.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=43&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=33&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?id_news=324642', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=50&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=50&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=50&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=89&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=89&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=89&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=89&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=89&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?id_news=226037', 'http://www.askmelisboa.com', 'http://www.portugaldigital.com.br', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/banner.swf', 'http://www.jtm.com.mo/', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=33&amp', 'http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/news.asp?section_id=33&amp', 'http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=1x1&type=richmedia&', 'http://bars.sapo.pt/bsu_v1.1/barra.js?site=diariodigital&amp', 'http://js.sl.pt/Netscope/']",440,460,131,1151,0,0,0,"Diário Digital @import url(includes/calendar/skins/aqua/theme.css); function SetHomepage() { document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; document.body.setHomePage('http://www.diariodigital.pt'); } _uacct = ""UA-195558-1""; urchinTracker(); /* v1.1 */ .bsu_almofada {clear: both;margin-bottom: 1.4em;overflow: hidden;height: 1px;font-size: 16px;} var TileID = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000); TileID=Math.floor(Math.random()*100000); Director: Pedro Curvelo Pesquise no DD em Todas as secções.. Sociedade Política Mundo Desporto Auto-Digital Cultura Ambiente Saúde Pessoas TV e Cinema Multimédia Informática Torne o DD a sua homepageterça-feira, 23 de Fevereiro de 2010 | 14:55 MUNDO POLÍTICA SOCIEDADE AMBIENTE SAÚDE PESSOAS ECONOMIA DESPORTO CULTURA TV E CINEMA MULTIMÉDIA INFORMÁTICA MÚSICA Outros artigos desta secção terça-feira, 29 de Dezembro de 2009 | 12:36 Imprimir Enviar por Email Polícia alemã testa scanner corporal para segurança aérea A Polícia alemã está a testar há um ano e meio os sistemas de scanner corporal para optimizar a segurança aérea, informaram hoje fontes policiais, depois de, nos últimos dias, terem aumentado os controlos dos passageiros com destino aos EUA. Os testes acontecem a portas fechadas, em dependências policiais de Lübeck (norte do país), e, até ao momento, não foi elaborado nenhum relatório sobre a sua eficiência nem estabelecido quanto tempo durarão as provas, acrescentou essa fonte. As autoridades alemãs, assim como outros países europeus e do resto do mundo, aumentaram o esquema de segurança e controlo dos viajantes para os EUA, após a tentativa de atentado realizada por um nigeriano num avião que fazia a ligação entre Amesterdão e Detroit. Os passageiros com destino aos EUA devem apresentar-se nos aeroportos antes do habitual, mas essas medidas provocaram alguns atrasos nas descolagens dos voos. A tentativa de atentado no avião com destino a Detroit abriu um debate na Alemanha sobre a segurança aérea, enquanto alguns especialistas advertem que esta não pode ficar 100% garantida nem mesmo com scanner corporal, que também representa uma restrição do direito à privacidade. CONTINUA ... function abrirjanela(theurl) { window.open(theurl,'print',""toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no,width=615,height=400""); } function abrirjanelaFriend(theurl) { window.open(theurl,'EnviarAmigo',""toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no,width=242,height=180""); } Canais Diário Digital OE2010: BE quer taxar a 25% transferências para off-shoresWall Street inicia sessão com ligeiras quedasFrente Comum desconvoca greve de 4 de Março na Madeira The National no Super Bock Super RockAgenda de concertos 23 de FevereiroPassatempo: A Dama de Copas e o Rei de Cuba // <![CDATA[ var so = new SWFObject(""images_banner/Tivoli-mrec.swf"", ""pub825"", ""300"", ""250"", ""9"", """"); so.write(""flashcontent825""); // ]]> & vbcrlf document.write ('<SCR' + 'IPT SRC=""http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=300x250&type=mrec&pos=2&TileID='+TileID+'""></SCR' + 'IPT>'); PassatempoDama de Copas e o Rei de Cuba Acerto de Contas Mundover maisPolíticaver maisSarkozy nomeia socialista para o Tribunal de ContasFarc atacam sedes de partidos na ColômbiaIrão: Ahmadinejad promete cortar mãos de agressores Holanda: Legislativas antecipadas marcadas para 9 de JunhoCarro armadilhado explode na Irlanda do NorteIrão disposto a comprar ou trocar combustível nuclear Secretário de Estado João Correia critica Cândida AlmeidaZapatero e Durão Barroso prometem apoio à MadeiraBE propõe fim dos benefícios fiscais para PPRFrente Comum desconvoca greve de 4 de Março na MadeiraDirector do Sol pede adiamento da audição parlamentarAR aprova deliberação de solidariedade com a Madeira Sociedadever maisEconomiaver maisProvedor de Justiça recomenda alteração de dois diplomasMadeira: Bispo do Funchal presidiu ao primeiro funeralSMMP «estupefacto» com declarações de Cândida AlmeidaMetro do Porto contesta providência cautelar ao concursoMadeira: Governo reduz para 13 número de desaparecidosInternamento de Valentim Loureiro adia debate instrutórioOE2010: BE quer taxar a 25% transferências para off-shoresWall Street inicia sessão com ligeiras quedasBanif recorre a tribunal para recuperar 13 M€ nos AçoresLufthansa cancela voos apesar de suspensão da greve pilotosBrasil: BRIC são a «tropa de elite da economia mundial»FMI: Fim dos apoios à economia deve ser «concertado»Saúdever maisPessoasver maisCascais: 50 manifestantes protestam frente ao novo hospitalCientistas criam mosquito transgénico para conter dengueNovo Hospital de Cascais é hoje inauguradoMenos de metade dos portugueses foram ao dentista em 2009Instituto Macrobiótico promove workshop de geobiologiaEstudo vai inquirir doentes sobre morte assistidaNicole Scherzinger e Lewis Hamilton reconciliam-seJennifer Lopez deixa Sony Music e atrasa novo CDHaiti: Vestido de Britney Spears rende 5.878 eurosLindsay Lohan admite abuso de drogasFerrán Adriá anuncia fundação no Restaurante elBulli em 2014América Latina: Shakira lança fundo para a infânciaDesportover maisCulturaver maisSporting: Moutinho informou-se sobre o interesse do ZenitSp. Braga promete abrir as portas do estádio com o OlhanenseFC Porto: Fernando com rotura muscularI Liga: Leixões e Wires lideram nas faltas cometidasI Liga: FC Porto e Hulk lideram perdas de bolaI Liga: William é o que mais «cai» em fora de jogoSiza Vieira entre 200 criadores para «vazio» do Guggenheim SLTM acolhe Semana da Cultura Açoriana de 2 a 7 de Março*Veja programa no interior...Coimbra: Eduardo Pitta na livraria Almedina Estádio dia 25Braga: Theatro Circo acolhe «niewZwart» dia 28 de FevereiroGastronomia de Macau em destaque no MdO em MarçoCiclo «Grandes Pianistas» abre dia 26 com Artur PizarroTV e Cinemaver maisAmbientever maisNGC estreia «Caçadores de Cabeças da II Guerra» em MarçoOwen Wilson protagonizará próximo filme de Woody AllenEUA vai produzir série inspirada em conta do TwitterMichael Jackson: «Captain EO» volta a ser exibido na DisneyShia LaBeauf aprende a jogar na Bolsa para «Wall Street 2»Taylor Lautner protagonizará «Abduction»Vento arranca 300 azinheiras centenárias em Nisa e CratoNovo Aeroporto: Medidas de minimização custarão até 150 M€Aviação: OACI fixa 2013 como meta para criar norma sobre CO2Navios deixam 135 toneladas de lixo no FunchalHora do Planeta: Lisboa e Faro às escuras dia 27 de MarçoBaleias: Austrália ameaça avançar com acção contra JapãoInformática e Multimédiaver maisMúsicaver mais«SOS Madeira» reúne 30 mil membros no FacebookNova Iorque: Apple Store acolhe casamento entre nerdsAmazon e Microsoft assinam acordo para partilhar patentes Timor Telecom muda imagem e anuncia rede 3GFacebook eleita a empresa mais inovadora do mundo Grupo Renascença reorganizado em «r/com Multimédia» The National no Super Bock Super RockPassatempo: A Dama de Copas e o Rei de CubaA Silent Film regressam a PortugalSuper Bock Super Rock muda-se para o MecoMotorhead no Rock In Rio document.write ('<SCR' + 'IPT SRC=""http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=300x250&type=mrec&pos=1&TileID='+TileID+'""></SCR' + 'IPT>'); document.write ('<SCR' + 'IPT SRC=""http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=300x100&type=banner&pos=2&TileID='+TileID+'""></SCR' + 'IPT>'); TempoMercados Clique para aceder ao ticker function popW(){window.open(""ddTik.asp"",""Ticker"",""toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,copyhistory=no,width=520,height=100"")}PSI20 -43.4 7,690.93 -0.56 HoróscopoNewsletterAUTO-DIGITALAPRESENTAÇÃO NACIONALChevrolet Spark LIVROS«O Terceiro Reich»: 1º capítuloDepois de «2666», a Quetzal edita mais uma obra do chileno Roberto Bolaño, «O Terceiro Reich», que terá lançamento oficial durante as Correntes d´Escritas na próxima quinta-feira. Portugal será o segundo país a nível mundial a ver editado o livro póstumo de Bolãno.Mundial 2010Calendário do Mundial 201015/06: Costa do Marfim-PORTUGAL 21/06: PORTUGAL-Coreia do Norte 25/06: PORTUGAL-BrasilUtilidadesEscolha uma opção...Agenda do DiaDiário da RepúblicaFarmáciasEP - TrânsitoProgramação TVImprensa do DiaEscolha uma opção...Diário de NotíciasPúblicoExpressoDiário EconómicoA BolaRecordO JogoFinancial TimesSolJornal de NegóciosServiçosEscolha uma opção...RSSSMSWAP / PDATicker NotíciasNewsLetterE-DiárioChatWebmailSondagemSócrates continua a ter condições para governar?SimNão <!-- function CheckVote(theOption) { check = false; for (i=0;i<25;i++) { if (theOption.answer[i]) { if (theOption.answer[i].checked) { window.open('','Result',""toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no,width=270,height=270""); check=true; break; } } else break; } if (check==false) alert(""Por favor selecione uma opção para votar""); return check; } // --> Opinião Digital«Ética: mais do mesmo?»Dom Vasco Teles da Gama«Quando é que se indignam?»Fátima Moura da Silva«Com Papas e Bolos »João Mattos e SilvaCinemaESTREIAS A 18 DE FEVEREIRO«O Lobisomem» «An Education» «Bobby Cassidy: Counterpuncher» «Um Homem Sério» «Um Homem Singular» // <![CDATA[ var so = new SWFObject(""http://diariodigital.sapo.pt/banner.swf"", ""pub0001"", ""120"", ""130"", ""9"", """"); so.write(""flashcontent""); // ]]> Copyright Diário Digital 1999/2010 Av. da Liberdade, nº13 - 3ºEsq. 1250-139 LisboaTelefone: 21.359.31.00 | Fax: 21.359.31.31Propriedade: Caneta Electrónica - Edições Multimédia , SAEmpresa jornalística: 223 356 * Registo de título: 123 357Membro da Associação Portuguesa de Imprensa Ficha Técnica | Estatuto editorial | E-mail document.write ('<SCR' + 'IPT SRC=""http://ads.sapo.pt/js.ng/site=diariodigital&chan=diariodigital&adsize=1x1&type=richmedia& TileID='+TileID+'""></SCR' + 'IPT>'); var WRP_ID= 312223; var WRP_SECTION_GRP='Noticias'; var WRP_SUBSECTION_GRP= 'Diario Digital (312223)'; var WRP_CONTENT='Home content'; var WRP_CHANNEL; var WRP_SECTION=''; var WRP_SUBSECTION=''; WRP_SECTION='Homepage'; WRP_SUBSECTION='Artigo'; webo_ok=0; /* Profondeur Frame */ var WRP_ACC ; wreport_ok=0; if(wreport_ok==1){ var w_counter = new wreport_counter(WRP_SECTION, WRP_SUBSECTION, WRP_ID, WRP_ACC, WRP_CHANNEL, WRP_SECTION_GRP, WRP_SUBSECTION_GRP); w_counter.add_content(WRP_CONTENT); w_counter.count();}",,0,0,0,[[]],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,153,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,202,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,17,0,6,1,155,11,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0,4,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,62,0,179,0,0,0,0,0,1,98,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"ID
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
11    11
12    12
13    13
14    14
...
1005    1005
1006    1006
1007    1007
1008    1008
1009    1009
1010    1010
1011    1011
1012    1012
1013    1013
1014    1014
1015    1015
1016    1016
1017    1017
1018    1018
1019    1019
Length: 1020, dtype: int64",0
    ...
2200976,22,./dataset_html/diario_digital/4446001.html,976,br,6,0,td,973.0,0,0,0,[],0,0,0,[],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,0,[[]],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"ID
    0     2200000
    1     2200001
    2     2200002
    3     2200003
    4     2200004
    5     2200005
    6     2200006
    7     2200007
    8     2200008
    9     2200009
    10    2200010
    11    2200011
    12    2200012
    13    2200013
    14    2200014
    ...
    977    2200977
    978    2200978
    979    2200979
    980    2200980
    981    2200981
    982    2200982
    983    2200983
    984    2200984
    985    2200985
    986    2200986
    987    2200987
    988    2200988
    989    2200989
    990    2200990
    991    2200991
    Length: 992, dtype: int64",2200976
```

Inputs are a couple (>3000) of mixed data dataframes (big ones) that I'm not able to copy here, not even a single row.

The excerpt of the code I use is as following:

```
for picklefile in pickleFiles: 
    if count%100 == 0:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        print(str(t2))
        print('count = ' + str(count))
        print('time: ' + str(t2 - t1) + '\n')
        t1 = t2

    #DataFrame Manipulation:
    df = pd.read_pickle(path + picklefile)
    df['Concatenated String Index'] = str(100000*df.FileID + df.ID).zfill(10)
    df['ConcatIndex'] = 100000*df.FileID + df.ID
    df.index = df.ConcatIndex

    #DataFrame Normalization:
    #TODO: Cycle that normalizes every column in each DataFrame...

    #Saving DataFrame in different formats:
    df.to_pickle(path + "Normalized/Pickle/" + picklefile)
    df.to_csv(path + 'Normalized/CSV/' + picklefile.strip('.p') + '.csv')

    if picklefile == '0000.p':
        f = open('teste.txt', 'w')
        f.write(pd.DataFrame.to_string(df))
        f.close

        df.to_csv(finalnormCSVFile)
    else:
        df.to_csv(finalnormCSVFile, mode='a', header=False)

    count += 1
```

Desired Output, base csv format like the following:

```
Index, head1, head2, head3, ...
0, value1, value2, value3, ...
1, value1, value2, value3, ...
2, value1, value2, value3, ...
3, value1, value2, value3, ...
4, value1, value2, value3, ...
...
etc.
```

How can I change this and get a full row-based csv output?

Comment: Can you show a few lines of the data before outputting it and also a few lines of desired output?  Please also show the full ```to_csv``` command, especially if you use any flags.

Comment: @JohnE I've added what you asked.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I don't have any ideas to suggest.  Looks like the issue is more with what you're reading in than writing out though.

Comment: I've taken another look and suspect it might have something to do with this line of code: "df['Concatenated String Index'] = str(100000*df.FileID + df.ID).zfill(10)". What do you think?

Comment: @CMPSoares Try using df.info() along the way to understand where the df gets polluted. I suspect that it might be one of the pickles that caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that this part of the script was doing all the damage:

```
    #DataFrame Manipulation:
    df = pd.read_pickle(path + picklefile)
 -> df['Concatenated String Index'] = str(100000*df.FileID + df.ID).zfill(10)
    df['ConcatIndex'] = 100000*df.FileID + df.ID
    df.index = df.ConcatIndex
```

When transforming those indexes to a string it returns the string of the whole transformed index and that's why it appeared strange. Turned that line of code into a for each loop and works out fine.